# Emberjs: Many To Many Json Param Not Being Sent

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data

ember-cli 1.13.8

ember-data 1.13.11

ActiveModelAdapter

I have two objects: posts and users. I have an action on an individual post page that let users watch/follow the post.

```
//post model js
watchedUsers: DS.hasMany('user', { inverse: 'watchedPosts', async: true });

//user model js
watchedPosts: DS.hasMany('post', {inverse: 'watchedUsers', async: true });

//action after clicking button
action: {
    addToWatchlist(post) {
        //session.current user is declared in an initializer that lets us access the current user easily
        post.get('watchedUsers').pushObject(this.get('session.currentUser'));

        post.save().then(function() {
            console.log('post save success');
        }, function() {
            console.log('post save fail');
        }
    }
}
```

In ember inspector after clicking the follow button, I see that the attribute watchedUsers for the post model update, and watchedPosts for user model update. The values disappear when I refresh. With this, I think the pushObject function itself is fine.

When looking at my `PUT` request to my backend to save the post model, it does not contain the json entry for the `watched_user_ids`. (so it is not being saved, duh) *I believe this is my main problem.*

I have seeded data in my rails backend that I can see/access on the ember side, so I know that the json is accessible one way. Does ember-data not support many-to-many yet? Is there something special I have to do to send/save the json for a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: If you look at the request body is there a watched_user array being populated with ids ?

Comment: No, everything but my many to many attribute is being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, but using a 'watchlist' object in the middle of Post and User that represented their many to many relationship. The backend/rails side it done with a many to many :through, instead of a has and belongs to many. It seems like Ember Data does not send json for HasMany attributes, which was my main problem.

Here's what the final solution looked like:

```
//models/user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
     watchlists: DS.hasMany('watchlist', { async: true })
});

//models/post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
     watchlists: DS.hasMany('watchlist', { async: true })
});

//models/watchlists.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
    listing: DS.belongsTo('listing', { async: true }),
});

//action in a route.js
actions: {
    addToWatchlist(post) { //component sends the specific post using sendAction
        var newWatchlist = this.store.createRecord('watchlist', {
            user: this.get('session.currentUser'), //current user stored in session object
            post: post
        });
        newWatchlist.save();
    }
}
```